# Running flask app with gunicorn and environment variables

Tags: flask, environment-variables, gunicorn

For local development I simply set .env file that contain necessarily variables and just run the app with:

`Flask run`

Everything seems fine, all the environment variables are being read and set correctly in the app.

However when I run the app with gunicorn:

`gunicorn api:app --bind 127.0.0.1:5050`

I can see clearly that env variables are not loaded.

Only If I set them explicitly in gunicorn command:

`gunicorn api:app --bind 127.0.0.1:5057 -e POSTGRES_DB=postgresql://XXXXX`

then it will work.
However since I can have many environment variables this is not really feasible. Is there a way to set this using file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Gunicorn can read `gunicorn.conf.py` file which is just a normal python file where you can set your environment variables:

```
# gunicorn.conf.py
import os
os.environ['POSTGRES_DB'] = "postgresql://XXXXX"
```

You can even tell it to load your `.env` files with something like:

```
# gunicorn.conf.py
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

for env_file in ('.env', '.flaskenv'):
    env = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), env_file)
    if os.path.exists(env):
        load_dotenv(env)
```