# SMTPServerDisconnected When Sending via Flask-Mail on Gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, smtplib

I have a Flask app deployed with Gunicorn & Nginx and I am trying to debug a strange issue I am having with sending emails from the application (via Flask-Mail library). Sending emails works from my local development environment and also works on my server (on Digital Ocean) if I start my application via the `flask run` command. This is important as most of the answers I have found mention that their hosting provider blocks outgoing mail over the default SMTP port.

Once I try to send any email from the application hosted in Gunicorn I get the following error in my logs -

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 365, in send
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected('please run connect() first')
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: please run connect() first
```

My application is launched in Gunicorn via the below command -

```
gunicorn --workers 3 \
    --timeout 120 \
    --bind 0.0.0.0:9000 \
    --log-file=dt.log \
    --bind unix:dt.sock -m 007 \
    --log-level=info wsgi:app
```

I have created a very simple route to send an email and I see the same behavior as my existing code. This is the route I created.

```py
@bp.route("/debugmail")
def debugmail():
    msg = Message(
        "An Email Subject!",
        sender=("Email Sender Name", "emailfromsample@gmail.com"),
        recipients=["ping@pong.com"],
    )
    msg.body = "This is an email from the App (tons of uses for this)."
    
    # Also Tried Adding the Connect Command Here
    # mail.connect()
    mail.send(msg)
    return {"message": "Email sent!"}, 200
```

The configuration file I use for this app is below -

```yaml
MAIL_SERVER=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USE_TLS=True
MAIL_USE_SSL=False
MAIL_USERNAME=username@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=app-specific-password
```

Any help or thoughts or tests for me to run would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: where do you create `mail`?  Maybe you should recreate it inside `debugmail` and run `mail.connect()`

Comment: `mail` is created in my `create_app()` function when the Flask app is initiated. If that were the problem, I wouldn't be able to send email when not running outside of Gunicorn & I believe Flask-Mail handles all connectivity establishment.

Comment: Gunicorn runs flask in different way - it use many processes and maybe this makes problem - it may need to run `connect()` manually when you send mail

Comment: I tried to add `mail.connect()` to my code and I still receive the same error. I updated my original post to show where I added it.

Comment: it may need `smtplib.connect( server, port, login, password )`

Comment: Your comment gave me an idea and I have solved it (see below).

Comment: it would be nice to see solution in answer because problem seems strange

Comment: I was using `.flaskenv` for Flask variables and `.env` for non-Flask variables and Gunicorn doesn't load in `.env` by default so I added it to a `gunicorn.conf.py` file without changing any code and it worked as expected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that by using a `.env` file that Flask was able to read automatically, was not passed into the context of the Gunicorn runner.

As per the answer linked belo, I have created this file which guarantees that both my `.flaskenv` and `.env` load no matter the context.

[Running flask app with gunicorn and environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68622148/running-flask-app-with-gunicorn-and-environment-variables)

```py
# gunicorn.conf.py
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

for env_file in ('.env', '.flaskenv'):
    env = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), env_file)
    if os.path.exists(env):
        load_dotenv(env)
```